# How to get return value of "export default" from importing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

to put it simply, I have a `js` file with export default that return an object.

```js
// x.js
export default ()=>({
  text: 'text'
})
```

I wanna import it in another `js` file and merge it with its data (kinda extend it).
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```js
// y.js
import x from './x.js';
const obj = x()
export default ()=>({
  ...obj,
  text2: "text2"
})
```

It is working but not clean. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just return the object?

Comment: Is it mandatory to export a function?

Comment: You'd only need a function only if you mutate an object in the place where you consume it and don't want it to affect other places.

Comment: @NehaSoni unfortunately yes. it's mandatory to use export default. its i18n structure in nuxt.js

Comment: What exactly do you feel is not clean?

Comment: @Bergi , that `const obj` variable which needs allocating memory

Comment: Well if you want to call `x()` only once, that's what you have to do. Otherwise you can of course also just write `export default () => ({...x(), text2: "text2"});`

Answer (score 0):

From *"I want to use a clean approach"*, I assume, an approach that is easy to understand. So, the following approaches could be useful-

**1. Default Exports-**
This is useful to export only a single object, function, or variable. During the import, we can use any name to import.

```
// x.js
export default function xFunc() {
    return { text: "text" };
}

//y.js
import xFunc from "./x.js";
export default function yFunc() {
    return {
        ...xFunc(),
        text2: "text2",
    };
}

// import y in any file
import yFunc from "./y";
console.log(yFunc());
```

**Default Exports can also be used in this way-**
This is useful as we can use any name for fun because it is a default export with a name (so we can remember the name) and import with any name.

```
// x.js
function xFunc() {
  return { text: "text" };
}
export { xFunc as default };

// y.js
import anyName from "./x.js";
function yFunc() {
  return {
    ...anyName(),
    text2: "text2",
  };
}
export { yFunc as default };

// import y in any file
import anyName from "./y";
console.log(anyName());
```

**2. Named Exports (Recommended)-**
This is useful to export several values. During the import, it is mandatory to use the same name which avoids confusion between exported and imported name.

```
// x.js
export const xFunc = () => { text: "text" };

//y.js
import { xFunc } from "./x.js";
export const yFunc = () => {
  return {
    ...xFunc(),
    text2: "text2",
  };
};

// import y in any file
import { yFunc } from "./y";
console.log(yFunc());
```

**EDIT--**

Named exports can also be used like this (without using const and arrow function)

```
// x.js
function xFunc() {
  return { text: "text" };
}
export { xFunc };

//y.js
import { xFunc } from "./x.js";
function yFunc() {
  return {
    ...xFunc(),
    text2: "text2",
  };
}
export { yFunc };

// import y in any file
import { yFunc } from "./y";
console.log(yFunc());
```

Comment: Your first and second example are exactly equivalent, default-exporting named function declarations.

Comment: In your third example, why switch from named function declarations to `const` + arrow functions?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote, "Default Exports can also be used in this way-". There are multiple syntaxes.

Comment: Ah, it's just that "*the following approaches could be useful*" sounded like you considered them different approaches. I was also confused why you remarked "*a default export with a name (so we can remember the name)*" since the previous example already had the same.

Comment: Const, is to ensure the line I wrote, "it is mandatory to use the same name which avoids confusion between exported and imported name"

Comment: I got your point, let me use a numbered list.